# Is There a way to customize the IN/Company link for LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I have inherited some code which uses uses the LinkedIn Company Profile API. At least that's what I think it is. Basically a script tag is rendered in the following format:

```
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="9999" data-format="click"></script>
```

This together with .js file creates a link with the Linked-in logo which when clicked on reveals profile of company. Question is, can I customize the link. I want to add some text to the right of the linked in logo. I couldn't find any relevant documentation on it. I added a span tag with some text and attempted to wire up the click of the span, so that when clicked it clicks the linkedin icon. That doesn't seem to work-- which I found rather odd.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Company Profile plugin builder is here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile-plugin

Customization of this plugin is limited to width (using data-width) at this time because of the complex layout.  However, you could build something similar using the Javascript API if you need something more customized to your system.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option that is more customizable, but has less interactivity:
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/profile-badges